# How to mask columns in Hive using REGEXP_REPLACE?

Tags: hive, masking

I am trying to achieve the below requirement of masking of address fields in Hive using regexp_replace.

If I have an address field I need to retain characters in 1,4,8,12 ..etc (multiples of 4) position and replace remaining characters as 'X', Spaces should be retained.

I have achieved the result in Teradata but struggling with Hive SQL using the same function and arguments.

Teradata Code:

```
SELECT 
RegExp_Replace(RegExp_Replace(
RegExp_Replace
('CHANGI COURT', '(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?', '(\1(\2[\3(\4', 2,0,'c'),'(\([^ ])', 'X', 1,0,'c'),'(\(|\[)', '', 1,0,'c');
```

Teradata Result working as expected:

> CXXNXX CXXXT

Hive Code:

```
SELECT 
RegExp_Replace(RegExp_Replace(
RegExp_Replace
('CHANGI COURT', '(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?', '(\1(\2[\3(\4', 2,0,'c'),'(\([^ ])', 'X', 1,0,'c'),'(\(|\[)', '', 1,0,'c');
```

Hive error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:37 Wrong arguments ''c'': 
>   No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace 
>   with (string, string, string, int, int, string). Possible choices: 
>   *FUNC*(string, string, string) (state=42000,code=10014)

I have attached the screenshots of the code and results for both Hive and Teradata as well.

Teradata Code:

[image: Working Teradata code]

Teradata Result:

[image: Teradata Resultset]

Hive code:

[image: Hive code]

Hive error:

[image: Hive code error]

Can this be achieved in HIVE?

Comment: @halfer .. thats correct the teradata code seems to give me the desired output in teradata but when i run the same code in hive it fails .. so was wondering if there any other way this could be achieved in hive. Hope this clarifies ..

Comment: @halfer .. I have edited my question with all the details .. hope it suffices.

Comment: definitely will make sure the next time i post or edit will follow the formatting rules of the forum ... if you have any ideas on whether this can be achieved in hive please let me know .. Thanks!

Comment: Issue has been resolved

Comment: What's the resolution? You may put your own answer as solution and accept it. This way, it'll be helpful for the community as well.